# Monitoring Integration points

Tags: integration-testing, monitoring, loadrunner, sitescope

Our company is working on integrating Guidewire(claims processing system) into the existing claims system. We will be executing performance tests on the integrated system shortly. I wanted to know if there was some way to monitor the integration points specific to guidewire. 
The system is connected through Web Services. We have access to Loadrunner and Sitescope, and are comfortable with using other open source tools also.

I realize monitoring WSDL files is an option, Could you suggest additional methods to monitor the integration points?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the architecture of Guidewire.  You OS have OS monitoring points and you have application monitoring points.    The OS is straightforward using SiteScope, SNMP (with SiteScope or LoadRunner), Hyperic, Native OS tools or a tool like Splunk.

You likely have a database involved:  This monitoring case is well known and understood.

Monitoring the services?   As the application experts inside of your organization what they look at to determine if the application is healthy and running well.  You might be implementing a set of terminal users (RTE) with datapoints, log monitoring through SiteScope, custom monitors scheduled to run on the host piping the output through SED to a standard form that can be imported into Analysis at the end of the test.

Think Architecturally.  Decompose each host in the stack into OS and services.   Map your known monitors to the hosts and layers.   Where you run into issues grab the application experts and have them write down the monitors they use (they will have more faith in your results and analysis as a result)